# Flutter riverpod: notify when specific columns are updated

Tags: flutter

I'm struggling to get notification when specific columns are updated.

I have CalcHeader and its StateNotifierProvider.

```
@freezed
abstract class CalcHeader with _$CalcHeader {
  const factory CalcHeader({
    required String id,
    required String title,
    required DateTime createdAt,
    required DateTime updatedAt,
    required List<CalcItem> calcItems,
    required String calcItemId,
    required int cursorIndex,
  }) = _CalcHeader;

  factory CalcHeader.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CalcHeaderFromJson(json);
}
```

```
class CalcHeaderListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<CalcHeader>> {
  static const String keyName = 'calcHeaders';

  CalcHeaderListNotifier()
      : super([]) {
    initialized();
  }

  final calcHeader = CalcHeader(
      id: const Uuid().v1(),
      title: '1',
      calcItems: [],
      createdAt: DateTime.now(),
      updatedAt: DateTime.now(),
      calcItemId: '',
      cursorIndex: 0);

  Future initialized() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final loaded = prefs.getStringList(keyName);
    if (loaded == null) {
      final result = await Common().saveCalcHeaderList([calcHeader]);
      if (result == true) {
        state = [calcHeader];
      }
    } else {
      state = loaded.map((f) => CalcHeader.fromJson(json.decode(f))).toList();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> add({required String title}) async {

    final calcHeaders = [...state, calcHeader];
    final result = await Common().saveCalcHeaderList(calcHeaders);
    if (result == true) {
      state = calcHeaders;
    }
    return result;
  }

  Future<void> update(List<CalcHeader> calcHeaders) async {
    await Common().saveCalcHeaderList(calcHeaders).then((value) {
      if (value == true) {
        state = calcHeaders;
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> delete({required String id}) async {
    final newList = state.where((calcHeader) => calcHeader.id != id).toList();
    await Common().saveCalcHeaderList([...newList]).then((value) {
      if (value == true) {
        state = [...newList];
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateCalcItems(String calcHeaderId, List<CalcItem> items) async {
    ...
  }

}
```

Now, I define calcHeaderListProvider like below, I get all notification when any column is updated such as calcItems.

```
final calcHeaderListProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CalcHeaderListNotifier, List<CalcHeader>>(
  (ref) => CalcHeaderListNotifier(),
);
```

What I want to do is to get notification only when the following columns are updated.
Because My app has a header section and a detail section, and the CalcHeader class has both items.

```
    required String id,
    required String title,
    required DateTime createdAt,
    required DateTime updatedAt,
```

Is there any good solution?

Comment: See https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AlwaysAliveProviderBase/select.html